# Understand build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am trying to understand build.gradle file. Is it proper Groovy code?

for example:

```
  plugins {
      id 'groovy'
  }
```

is what exactly? Is it an override of some field or some method invocation? is it between `{}` a lambda? What is going on?

After investigation, I think that this may be a method named `plugins` invocation with a parameter that is a closure `{id 'groovy'}`.
The body of closure looks like a method `id` call with an argument `'groovy'`.

I wonder if this whole `build.gradle` file is a Groovy class inside the hood and it just runs the code in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Groovy plus Gradle's DSL builder.

DSL builders allow to either structure your XML- or JSON- output, or define the order and scope of operations, like in Gradle, and sprinkle it with "normal" code, like loops or control statements.

The code above translates roughly to:

```
project.plugins().apply( 'groovy' )
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginContainer.html